# What version of ruby use with cygwin?

Tags: ruby, windows, cygwin

I'm using cygwin and install on them ruby, so cause I don't have much experiences with ruby I always get much error that those version is buggy to use fix, and many more... So my question is what version of ruby use with cygwin, that bypass all those problems?

Comment: You don't need Cygwin to use Ruby.  There are native Win32 versions.

Comment: what is that native Win32 version?

Comment: the newest version seems that have aloso some bugs ..

Comment: http://www.ironruby.net/, http://rubyforge.org/projects/rubyinstaller/, etc.  IronRuby is .net, and the other seems to be built with MinGW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend installing the latest version from [rubyinstaller.org](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) as well as the devkit from the same page.
When you install it choose the option to add ruby to your path.

To get gem and the other batch files working correctly from cygwin you can add something like this to your .bash_profile:

```
ruby=`which ruby|perl -pe 's/\/[^\/]*$//'`
for i in `/bin/ls -1 $ruby/*.bat`
do
  alias `basename "$i" .bat`=$i
done
```